# Use of invention molds without permission

Tags: international

someone may be using our molds in China to produce products they do not have permission to do so. what can we do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Patents are territorial rights if the invention was patented in China then you can issue a cease and desist notice covering all aspects which you feel have protection in said territory.